# Graphics issue on older notebook with Radeon RS690

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I am setting up an older notebook (Toshiba Satellite A210-151) which we want to donate to a girl in Africa.

All seem to work fine so far, but when starting gnome-software I see artifacts. Now I am worried that this issue might also come up in other situations / when using other applications.

Here is a photo how the issue looks like:

[image: Here is a photo how the issue looks like]

[Here is a video showing the whole dilemma](https://nextcloud.fubsle.dynv6.net/s/T6zq5BX9sWonLSP?)

The issue is the same on Xubuntu 22.10 and 23.04. The articles I found so far are 10 years old and do not fit to current driver situation and Linux kernel.

```
$ sudo Ispci -vin | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatable controller (0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. (AMD/ATI) R$690M (Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/12701 (1002:791f1 (prog-if 00 (VGA controlle r])

$ glxinfo -B 
name of display: :0.0 display: :0 screen: direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX MESA query renderer):
Vendor: Mesa (0x1002)
Device: ATI R$690 (0x791f)
Version: 23.0.2
Accelerated: yes
Video memory: 128MB
Unified memory: no
Preferred profile: compat (0x2)
Max core profile version: 0.0
Max compat profile version: 2.1
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa
OpenGL renderer string: ATI R$690
OpenGL version string: 2,1 Mesa 23,0,2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1,20
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2,0 Mesa 23,0,2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string, OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1,0, 16
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display
 description: VGA compatible controller 
 product: R5690M Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270] 
 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
 physical id: 5
 bus info: pci@0000: 01:05.0 
 logical name: /dev/fbo 
 version: 00 width: 64 bits
 clock: 33MHz
 capabilities: pm mi vga controller bus master cap list rom fb 
 configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=64 resolution=1280,800
 resources: irq:27 memory: f9000000-f7ffffff memory: f8100000-f810ffff ioport: 9000(size-256) memory: f8000000-f80fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: For hardware this old (2007), Ubuntu is not the best choice to say the least. Xubuntu or Lubuntu might work a bit better, but I'd try [AntiX](https://antixlinux.com/). That said, I am not sure how useful it will be with any OS, even in Africa.